# Someone asking money for help to pay taxes of kin claiming fund in UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, scams

Please help me. I'm in contact with someone who is an American soldier. He said that UK HM Revenue & Customs asked him to pay a large amount to recover the funds of his dead father. The total amount is £1,900,000 and the total tax is £109,500.
Is it true that the UK is asking him to pay the taxes to recover the fund?

Comment: Yeah, no. Scam. Run away. Why would he ask you rather than a UK solicitor / lawyer to work out an estate issue?

Comment: Why would the person ask you, a stranger, for money?

Answer (score 14):

This is a scam.  Do not give them any money.

A quick search on this site will yield many examples of this scam.

Answer (score 10):

How can I say this more clearly? ***SCAM, SCAM, SCAM***!

This is another one of the oldest scams out there, where you've won a prize or an inheritance has come in, and all you have to do is pay the taxes on it to claim it.

*Don't be a sucker*!  Ask yourself why the government couldn't (and wouldn't) just take the taxes due out of the funds they have and give the rest to the person they belong to?  Wouldn't that be the smartest and easiest thing to do?

As an example, let's say that you have $1,000 that belongs to me, and I owe you $100.  Would you tell me to pay you the $100 and then you'll give me the $1,000 or would you take the $100 I owe you out of the $1,000 and give me the remaining $900?

The fact this is someone you know from the internet and they want your "help" to claim their money should tell you how much of a scam this is.

**Stop talking to this person, *and don't tell them anything personal about you***.  They are scam artists, and whatever you tell them could be used to steal your identity or take your money.

Be careful, my friend!

Answer (score 7):

Think about it... If the government has the money why would the government need more money to cover the tax on the money that the government already has?  Couldn't the government just withhold 109,500 from the 1,900,000 it's holding already?

Comment: FYI, that is what most governments do when they have hold of money and taxes are owed. Just take their cut and make the rest "somewhat" available. I do not know UK procedures, but probably is like that.

Comment: I'm sure the "soldier" has some quick answer to that, but of course, that's the right easy way to tell this is a scam.

Answer (score 6):

This is a scam. There is no soldier, no money ... This is a story to gain sympathy and make one part with Bank account and other details so that the scammer can make away with your money.

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that this is a scam (you ask a British solicitor for help with this sort of problem, not an American friend) but it's not as obvious as some answers seem to assume. Inheritance taxes always have to be paid before legacies can be received, and the funds are part of the estate not "in the hands of the government". There are certainly ways round the problem (which vary by country), but *if* the facts were as the asker sets out, this would be a reasonable request. You can bet they aren't and it isn't.